# Convert the mysql date format to dd-mmm-yyyy in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have maintained a table with start_date as "date" datatype and now I wanted to display the date in dd-mmm-yyyy format.

```
public static BusObjectIterator<com.timesheetmd.weeksView> weeksOfYear(int year)
{
    String queryText = "SELECT `id`, `year`, CONCAT(CAST(`start_date` AS CHAR), ' to ', CAST(`end_date` AS CHAR)) AS 'week' FROM `weeks` WHERE `weeks`.`year` = :year AND end_date <= CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY start_date DESC";
QueryObject query = new QueryObject(queryText);
query.addParameter("year", "weeks.year ", QueryObject.PARAM_INT,year);//NOPMD
query.setResultClass(weeksView.class);
return query.getObjects();
}
```

As I want to return the result in the form of BusObjectIterator. Is it possible to change the format of the date in the query itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You  need `DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%d-%b-%Y')` instead of your `CAST(...AS CHAR)`.

Here's the [DATE_FORMAT() writeup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: If I use DATE_FORMAT. Will it affect the return type?

Comment: You've had a string by your concatenation, it will remain a string. You don't need to cast it anymore though.